# How do I create a new Pandas Dataframe Column with data from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe created from a dict of lists. 
I want to split up those entries under the dates and create a new column called 'Story'.

```
                             2017-01-31           2017-02-01
 Gates, Bill.            [[SPGC-14075, 0.5]]                  [0]
 Jobs, Steve.            [[SPGC-14075, 3.5]]                  [0]
 Jobs, Steve.             [[SPGC-9456, 2.5]]                  [0]
 White, John ANDERSON.  [[SPGC-14075, 1.75]]  [[SPGC-9456, 5.25]]
```

Ideal Output:

```
                         Story            2017-01-31    2017-02-01
 Gates, Bill.           SPGC-14075         0.5                   0
 Jobs, Steve.           SPGC-14075         3.5                   0
 Jobs, Steve.           SPGC-94562          .5                   0
 White, John ANDERSON.  SPGC-14075        1.75                   0
 White, John ANDERSON.  SPGC-9456            0                   5.25
```

How do I go about doing this using pandas dataframe operations?

EDIT:

Using nanojohn's solution I got this output. Pretty close. Still need to break up that last entry in 2017-02-01.

```
                       2017-01-31         2017-02-01       Story
Gates, Bill.                 0.50                  0  SPGC-14075
Jobs, Steve.                 3.50                  0  SPGC-14075
Jobs, Steve.                 2.50                  0   SPGC-9456
White, John ANDERSON.        1.75  [SPGC-9456, 5.25]  SPGC-14075
```

Comment: probably easiest to do it from the dictionaries of lists, isn't it? you edit your dicts before you create the dataframe.

Comment: Would I need to make the SPGCs keys inside the dict?

Comment: I would have thought that you would want `Story` as the key and the `'SPGC-...` as the value, but there are many ways of doing dict -> dataframe conversion.

Comment: Yeah that was my original thought as well. Make story the key and anything else after a value. Need to rework my dict then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `.apply()` method as follows (assuming that your DataFrame is in a variable called `df`):

```
df['Story'] = df['2017-01-31'].apply(lambda x: x[0][0])
df['2017-01-31'] = df['2017-01-31'].apply(lambda x: x[0][1])
df['2017-02-01'] = df['2017-02-01'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: I posted output of that solution into the original post. Seemed to work like 90% of the way.

Comment: as far as I know apply will never add new items to the row index